# How to copy only constraint of one data base to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two databases:

1. Parent.db
2. Child.db

Parent.db and Child.db, both contain the same data.
The only difference is Child.db does not contain any constraint (like primary key, foreign key, identity , ... ) which Parent.db has.

Now I want to copy only those constraints from parent.db to child.db.
I don't want to copy data.

Comment: You need to generate scripts for those constraints. Why did you create the second database without using scripts to generate all the constraints? primary and foreign keys won't be too bad but missing identities is kind of pain. You can't just set that property of an existing column. You have to create a new column with identity set to true, then copy the data, delete the original column and finally rename the new column to the original name.

Comment: The second db already contain data.

Comment: Then you are going to have to script the constraints you want from the first database and run that script on your second database. Look closely at the explanation about adding identity, it is a multi-step process.